# Trying to make a function that applys a gaussian filter, but I get the same image

Tags: python, opencv, gaussian

Original and Gaussian Image:
[image]

My code for applying a Gaussian filter to an image, but it does not work, giving me the same image as what I started with. For reference, the kernel is of size (5,5) with sigma 1.0

I am not allowed to use any opencv function, so thats why im doing it manually

My Kernel:

```
[[0.00296902 0.01330621 0.02193823 0.01330621 0.00296902]
 [0.01330621 0.0596343  0.09832033 0.0596343  0.01330621]
 [0.02193823 0.09832033 0.16210282 0.09832033 0.02193823]
 [0.01330621 0.0596343  0.09832033 0.0596343  0.01330621]
 [0.00296902 0.01330621 0.02193823 0.01330621 0.00296902]]
```

```py
def apply_filter(img, kernel):
    kernel_length = len(kernel)
    imx = len(img)
    imy = len(img[0])
    new_image = img[::, ::]
    start = time.time()
    print("Applying filter --> This may take a while")
    for i in range(kernel_length, imx - kernel_length):
        for j in range(kernel_length, imy - kernel_length):
            acc = 0
            for ki in range(kernel_length):
                for kj in range(kernel_length):
                    acc += img[i][j] * kernel[ki][kj]
            new_image[i][j] = acc
    end = time.time()
    print("Application of this filter done! Time taken is ", end - start)
    return new_image
```

Comment: Can you show us your kernel ?

Comment: Yes of course, I added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you compute the `acc` value, so the new pixel. You need to apply the kernel on the surrounding pixel of the current `i,j` pixel.

```
def apply_filter(img, kernel):
    kernel_length = len(kernel)
    imx, imy = img.shape[0:2]
    print(imx)
    print(imy)
    new_image = img[::, ::]
    start = time.time()
    print("Applying filter --> This may take a while")
    for i in range(kernel_length, imx - kernel_length):
        for j in range(kernel_length, imy - kernel_length):
            acc = 0
            for ki in range(kernel_length):
                for kj in range(kernel_length):
                    acc += img[i+ki-2][j+kj-2] * kernel[ki][kj]
            new_image[i][j] = acc
    end = time.time()
    print("Application of this filter done! Time taken is ", end - start)
    return new_image
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about that. And I assume the 2 comes from (5-1)/2, that is I should replace it by (kernel_length-1)//2?

Comment: Sure. I forgot to change this.